# Server crashing every 14 days, no bugcheck

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hardware, electrical-power, server-crashes

Every 14 days one of our Windows servers crashes. We have been trying to figure out what causes this but to no avail.

Today we noticed a pattern in the shutdowns of the server, happening every 14 days and happening at roughly the same time for 4 crashes before changing the crash times.

[Windows event log filtered by EventID 6008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfWjg.png)

We don't have any schedules that run on the server on 14 day intervals, and I find it unlikely its a memory issue as the server has 68GB of RAM and its unrealistic that its filling up.

[Task Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFnU.png)

For every 6008, there is also an Event 41 (Kernal-Power) but this doesn't include any useful information all EventData is 0x0

[Event 41 Bugcheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR6Od.png)

The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2, slightly dated but still in support

Comment: There's not nearly enough information from that log to tell what's going on, if there's nothing else in the logs, i'd start checking either the hardware itself, or start taking a look at the power coming in. I've rarely had a faulty PSU in a server, but I'm sure it happens. A dip in power due to another external event every two weeks does sound more in the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a PSU issue. The weird part is the PSUs never indicated any faults apart from the last crash when their indicator LEDs switched from their usual green to amber.

Upon swapping the PSUs a little over a month ago we've not had any crashes since. Still not 100% sure why the PSUs decided to fail in unison every 2 weeks, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In such random issue it's most likely a hardware problem.

Please update all firmware's and watch after.

If the hardware is a HP, run the latest proliant support pack.

If the hardware is a Dell, run the latest SSU. ([Dell Server Update Utility (SUU) - Guide and Download](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000123359/dell-emc-server-update-utility-suu-guide-and-download))

Or else check with the manufacturer.

Answer (score -2):

You may give a try to BlueScreenView by Nirsoft to view dump-data, hope it helps.